# Firestore unsubscribe is not a function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having some trouble on understanding the unsubscribe() function usage for detaching listeners.
I'd like detach listener every time that user click button show table for changing view options.
Actually this is my code.
Previously **query** was called **unsubscribe** as reported in the official Firestore documentation (I also tested the same example code from documentation in my project) and in console log always return `unsubscribe is not a function`

```
let query;

$(".btnShowTable").on("click", function () { 
   if(typeof query != "undefined") query.unsubscribe();
   createTable(param);
});

function createTable(param) {
   query = db.collection("test1/test2/"+param).orderBy("dataora", "desc").limit(10);
   query.onSnapshot(function (querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.docChanges().forEach(function (change) {
   // get datas
   });
 });

}
```

What should I change in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`query` is a [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query) type object, and you can see from the API documentation that it doesn't have an `unsubscribe()` function.  What you'll need to do is follow the instructions in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener).  It says that [onSnapshot()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query#onsnapshot) returns an unsubscribe function to call when it's time to unsubscribe.

```
// subscribe to query results
const unsubscribe = query.onSnapshot(...)

// later, unsubscribe the listener
unsubscribe()
```